# Nordic nrf24l01 and ROS not working together on the same Arduino board?

Tags: ros, arduino

i have a problem. I am using two Nordic nRF24l01 modules with two Arduinos,one to transmitt some data and second one to receive that data.I want to publish that data on some topic to ROS machine, but whenever I include in the same code both ROS and Nordic module, data cant be published on ROS machine. Otherwise each is working fine separately. Does anyone knows if the problem is in programme or in something else? Are they in some kind of "conflict" when used together? This is the code for receiver side, which should receive data and then publish them on ROS machine. The problem is definitely not in the pipe, bcs whenever I exclude ROS code, the data is received fine and showed in Serial Monitor.  I hope I explained the question clearly. Waiting for your valuable reply.

````c
#include <RF24.h>
#include <RF24_config.h>
#include <nRF24L01.h>
#include <printf.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <ros.h>
#include <geometry_msgs/Vector3.h>

RF24 radio(7, 8); // CE, CSN

ros::NodeHandle nh;
geometry_msgs::Vector3 vectorMsg;
ros::Publisher vectorPub("robot_position", &vectorMsg);

struct VectorData {
  float x;
  float y;
  float z;
};

VectorData receivedVector;

void setup() {
  //Serial.begin(115200);
  nh.initNode();
  nh.advertise(vectorPub);

  radio.begin();
  radio.openReadingPipe(1, 0xF0F0F0F0E1LL); // Set the address to receive data
  radio.startListening();

}

void loop() {
  if (radio.available()) {
    
    radio.read(&receivedVector, sizeof(receivedVector));
  
    vectorMsg.x = receivedVector.x;
    vectorMsg.y = receivedVector.y;
    vectorMsg.z = receivedVector.z;

    vectorPub.publish(&vectorMsg);
    nh.spinOnce();
  }
}
```
````